# VideoCapture result in distorted lines in image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to click an image from Webcam using OpenCV. My code is as follows.

```
VideoCapture cap0(0);
cap0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
cap0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
cap0 >> frame;
string fileName = "/0.jpg";
cout << fileName << endl;
imwrite(fileName, frame);
```

I am getting this image as output

[image]

You can see some weird lines in output., What is the possible reason and how i can eliminate these Please point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem in the acquisition driver, which doesn't transfer the right row data on every 41th row (43rd for the first pair !?), maybe using block transfers.

It seems that there is valid image data in these rows, but I can't identify where they could be coming from.

Comment: is there anyway i can fix that??

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri Query the technical support of the camera manufacturer and/or the BeagleBone forum.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: are you sure about the image size ?

Comment: yep. If i increase my image size i get Green Image. Reducing the size will effect my other processes

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: your answer seems to indicate that you do not master the image size parameters.

Comment: Elaborate if i am missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be electromagnetic interference in your case, try check it in usual conditions without electric line near camera, or make sheld for camera.

Comment: Well this code is working on BeagleBone Black and i am getting this issue. But when i run this code from my laptop it has no such interference. Also this doesn't answer where i have attacehd these same webcams to Gas and Water meters where i am getting same result...

Comment: Do you getting only one frame, or as I see in your code you do open camera before capturing every frame? May be these stripes appears on the first frame only ?

Comment: So I have to get second frame ??

Comment: It looks like camera model or/and camera driver issue, camera may initialize several frames. But it not guaranty that it is a solution. You can check by skipping first 10-20 frames for sure.

Comment: i tried 50 frames but all are same. :( dont know what else to do

Comment: Try another camera if you have one.